# Finding a suitable form factor for a given set of conditions

Tags: plotting, functions, fitting, algebraic-manipulation, code-request

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
a = 0.15;
A[z_] := -a z^2;
Temp[zh_,B_] := (zh^3*Exp[-3*A[zh] - B^2*zh^2])/(4*Pi*Integrate[\[Zeta]^3*
       Exp[(-B^2)*\[Zeta]^2 - 3*A[\[Zeta]]], {\[Zeta], 0, zh}]); 
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Temp[zh, B], {B, 0, 0.6, 0.1}]], {zh, 0.01, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.3, 3}, {0, 0.5}}]
```

where $A[z]$ is called the form factor which is an Ansatz and it gives me the plot as:
[image: T1 vs z1]

The above ansatz also makes sure that the dilaton field:

```
\[Phi][z_, B_] := NIntegrate[ Sqrt[(-(2/x))*(3*x*D[A[x], {x, 2}] - 3*x*D[A[x], {x, 1}]^2 + 6*D[A[x], {x, 1}] + 2*B^4*x^3 + 2*B^2*x)], {x, 0, z}]
```

is also real-valued for $B$ in the range of 0 to 0.6

The details of this model can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.01852) (pages 6-7)

Now I am faced with the problem, where I need to choose a different ansatz for $A[z]$ such that I satisfy the real valuedness of the dilaton field for B in range of 0 to 1 and also get the plot for Temperature as:

[image: T2 vs z2]

The above plot comes from the data generated by the following code:

```
c = 1.16; a = c/9; b = (5*c)/16; 

A[z_] := (-3/4)*Log[a*z^2 + 1] + (1/2)*Log[b*z^3 + 1] - (3/4)*Log[a*z^4 + 1]

T[(zh_)?NumericQ, (B_)?NumericQ] := (zh^3/(E^(3*A[zh])*(4*Pi*NIntegrate[x^3/E^(3*A[x]), {x, 0, zh}])))*
   (1 + (1/(1 - E^((-c)*zh^2))^2)*2*c*B^2*(NIntegrate[x^3/E^(3*A[x]), {x, 0, zh}]/E^(c*zh^2) - NIntegrate[x^3/(E^(3*A[x])*E^(c*x^2)), {x, 0, zh}]))

Plot[Evaluate[Table[T[zh, B], {B, 0, 0.6, 0.1}]], {zh, 0.01, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 3}, {0, 0.5}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["z", FontSize -> 14], Style["T", FontSize -> 14]}, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Table[StringForm["B=`1`", i], {i, 0, 0.6, 0.1}]], {0.11, 0.5}], 
  ImageSize -> 330]
```

The details of which can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06995) (pages 6-9).

I am free to choose $A$ as $A[z,B]$ as well. Any ideas on how to construct such an ansatz will be highly beneficial!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a serious answer one would need the data. I would try an expansion in polynomials of z and B.

Without any data one can try an heuristic Ansatz and play with it. E.g.:

```
a = 0.15;
A[z_] := -a z^2;
Temp[zh_, 
   B_] := (zh^3*Exp[-3*A[zh] - B^2*zh^2])/(4*Pi*
      Integrate[\[Zeta]^3*
        Exp[(-B^2)*\[Zeta]^2 - 3*A[\[Zeta]]], {\[Zeta], 0, zh}]) - 
   0.007 zh^2 -  0.05 Exp[-B^2] + 
   1 Exp[-B^2]  0.15 Exp[-0.5 (zh - 2.5)^2];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Temp[zh, B], {B, 0, 0.6, 0.1}]], {zh, 0.01, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.3, 3}, {0, 0.5}}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

"Temp" describes coarsely the wanted function form. We may improve by expanding the difference between "T" and "Temp" in a polynomial of zh and B. Toward this end, we need "T" and "Temp" and calculate the difference at several points:

```
   diff = Flatten[Table[{zh, B, T[zh, B] - Temp[zh, B]}, {zh, 0.01, 3, 0.1}, {B, 0 0.6, 0.1}], 1];
```

A polynomial model of zh and B is given by (note that you may improve by changing the upper limits):

```
mod = Table[zh^i B^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 2}] // Flatten;
```

The correction is given by:

```
corr = LinearModelFit[diff, mod, {zh, B}] // Normal;
```

and the corrected solution:

```
sol[zh_, B_] = Temp[zh, B] + corr;

Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol[zh, B], {B, 0, 0.6, 0.1}]], {zh, 0.01, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.1, 3}, {0, 0.5}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["z", FontSize -> 14], 
   Style["T", FontSize -> 14]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    Table[StringForm["B=`1`", i], {i, 0, 0.6, 0.1}]], {0.11, 0.5}], 
 ImageSize -> 330]
```

[image]

To get an idea about the errors, we may plot the difference between "sol" and "T";

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[T[zh, B] - sol[zh, B], {B, 0, 0.6, 0.1}]], {zh, 
  0.01, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer. I have edited my question so as to give the source of the data. Actually the formula of `Temp[zh]` is given by `-(Derivative[1][g][zh]/(4*Pi))`, (the details of g and other parameters are given in the links provided in the question), so we are not allowed to tweak with the expression of `Temp[zh]`. The only free parameter that we have is `A[z]` or `A[z,B]`.

Comment: Look at the addition to my answer.

Comment: Your idea of playing around with `Temp[zh, B]` is justified but pragmatically it would be very hard to put into practice, because of many constraints described for the model.

Comment: Then search another crude approximation and proceed as above.